# Radio button for checked jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have MVC application and I am trying to check a default radio button to start with.

My form code goes as follows:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{

<div>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, false) No
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, true) Yes

</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />

}
```

Now at the beginning, No is default selected and after changing it to Yes when I submit the form I want it to be back to No.

I tried many ways but it is not working.

Some ways i tried is as follows:-

```
$("#StageGate").prop("checked", true)
$("#StageGate").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

But nothing works.

**EDIT**

Rendered HTML is:-

```
<form action="/Url" id="form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">        
<div>

            <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StageGate field is required." id="StageGate" name="StageGate" type="radio" value="False"> No
            <input id="StageGate" name="StageGate" type="radio" value="True"> Yes

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">

</form>
```

Please guide me with a way that would help me send it back to No or Yes.

Comment: Post your rendered HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have TWO ID's of `StageGate` - ID's **must** be unique, consider giving similar elements common classes. Your jQuery syntax will work with `.prop("checked", true)` as long as you use unique ID's.

Comment: The ID is duplicating and I totally understand that. But I have one variable and want to have one output for that value.
Using multiple variable to get one value is not the option.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As tymeJV says the id's must be unique. If you have any constraint to set a unique id you can manipulate the elements in jquery using their class names as below.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item => item.StageGate, false, new {@class = "rdbtnno"}) No
@Html.RadioButtonFor(item => item.StageGate, true, new {@class = "rdbtnyes"}) Yes
```

and the jquery part

```
<script>
   $(function () {
      $(".rdbtnno").prop("checked", "checked");
  prop });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
            {

              <div>
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, false, new { @checked = "checked" }) No
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, true) Yes
              </div>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on tymeJV's answer, you just need to provide unique id's for each input.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, false, new {id = "stagegateno"}) No
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StageGate, true, new {id = "stagegateyes"}) Yes
```

Then to set it back to no with javascript:

```
$("#stagegateno").attr("checked", "checked")
```